# ID общей комнаты 0 или 1? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть чат, в нем групповые диалоги. И есть одна комната общая для всех пользователей. Как лучше поступить при проектировании БД?

1. Создать общую комнату с id 1.
2. Не добавлять эту комнату в БД, а в других таблицах ссылаться на нее через dialog_id = 0.

Я склоняюсь ко второму способу, но тогда нельзя будет использовать внешний ключ, ссылающийся на dialogs.dialog_id.

Comment: Как насчет сделать комнате признак - её тип (общая, приватная, админская и т.п.) ?

Comment: Тип диалогов указывается, вопрос - добавлять общую комнату в БД или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы создал общую комнату с id `0` или `-1`. Даже лучше `-1`, т. к. это не дефаултное значение. И вообще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1 - разработчики SO с этим согласны.

Comment: под словом "создал" вы подразумеваете добавление общего чата в таблицу диалогов? Или просто в других таблицах, ссылающихся на диалог указывать dialog_id = -1?

Comment: @Евгений, да, добавление в таблицу. Иначе ключи будут непроверяемыми.

Comment: тогда в чем преимущество ID 0 или -1 перед ID=1? Тем более, что поле ID - autoincrement и я даже не уверен, что в него можно добавить 0 или -1.

Comment: @Евгений, в mssql точно можно вставить конкретные id при автоинкременте, про mysql не знаю, но думаю, что тоже можно. Преимущество как раз в том, что оно константное и не зависит от автоинкремента.